# How to print the text of a function of a class from another file? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, printing

I would like to print the text "Ok, good" after clicking on a checkbox. The function is in a class of an external file. I've come close to the solution, but I'm doing something wrong.

I get error: `Button1_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Could anyone suggest me what am I wrong and how to fix? Thank you

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from x import class_example

window=Tk()
window.configure(bg='#f3f2f2')
style = ttk.Style(window)

def Button1_func(self):
    myclass = x.class_example(self)
    myclass.print_function()

Checkbutton1 = IntVar()

Button1 = Checkbutton(window, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, command=Button1_func())
Button1.place(x=1, y=48)

window.mainloop()
```

x.py

```
class class_example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 5

        def print_function(self):
            if self.number == 5:
                 print("Ok, good")
```

Comment: Is your `print_function(self):` function indented like that in your code?

Comment: @jezza_99 I removed that self, but I still have problems. Could you show me how I can solve? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem is that the function Button1_func is not in a class and thus doesn't require self so remove that

```
def Button1_func():
    myclass = class_example()
    myclass.print_function()
```

also unindent the `print_function` it should't be inside the `__init__`

Finaly change the

`Button1 = Checkbutton(window, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, command=Button1_func())`

to

`Button1 = Checkbutton(window, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, command=Button1_func)`

as your providing `Button1_func` not running it (`Button1_func()`)

and it worked on my side

working code(main.py)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from x import class_example

window=Tk()
window.configure(bg='#f3f2f2')
style = ttk.Style(window)

def Button1_func():
    myclass = class_example()
    myclass.print_function()

Checkbutton1 = IntVar()

Button1 = Checkbutton(window, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, command=Button1_func)
Button1.place(x=1, y=48)

window.mainloop()
```

x.py

```
class class_example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 5

    def print_function(self):
        if self.number == 5:
             print("Ok, good")
```

Comment: I removed the selfs you said, but I still have problems. I am new to Python. show me your code? However print_function I would like it inside __init__, just like I wrote.

Comment: The init works as a constuctor, it is only called when x.class_example() is ran and won't exsist after

Comment: Ok, now i get error AttributeError: 'class_example' object has no attribute 'print_function'

Comment: could you update the post with the new code as it's working on my side?

Comment: I wrote the same suggested code as you. I have copied and pasted the two yout files. With your same code I get NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Ok sorry I found the problem, because your already importing the class from x you can just remove the `x.` from the `x.class_example()`

Comment: Ok, wait a few minutes as I check the code.